# Divisor function of highly composite sets

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $D(x)$ be the set of all divisors of an integer $x$. For a set of integers $S$ let us define $\sigma_0(S)$ as $|\cup_{x \in S}D(x)|$. Define $HCS(n, k) = \max_{S \subseteq [n], |S| \leq k}\sigma_0(S)$. Trivially $HCS(n, 1) = \sigma_0(HCN_n)$, where $HCN_n$ is the largest [highly composite number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number) not exceeding $n$. Also $HCS(n, k) = n$ iff $k \geq \lceil n / 2 \rceil$.

**Question 1**: can we determine the asymptotics of $HCS(n, k)$ for a constant $k$? My guess would be that $HCS(n, k) \sim \alpha(k) HCS(n, 1)$ with a particular constant $\alpha(k)$, is it true? If yes, what is $\alpha(k)$?

**Question 2**: for what ranges of $k(n)$ can we find the asymptotics of $HCS(n, k(n))$?